# How to describe an optional object parameter with default values using JSDocs

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I don't if the title properly expressed what I am trying to do. But I have the following function:

```js
/**
 * @param {any} param1
 * How to describe the second parameter??
 * @returns {Object}
 */
function doSomething (param1, { property1 = null, property2 = null }){
  // do stuff
  return something
}
```

As questioned in the comment, using JSDocs, how would I describe the second parameter?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use square brackets `[]` to indicate optional parameters.
Like so:

```
/**
 * @param {any} param1
 * @param {Object} somethingWithProps - Some description
 * @param {string} [somethingWithProps.property1] - First property
 * @param {string} [somethingWithProps.property2] - Second property
 * @returns {Object}
 */
function doSomething (param1, { property1 = null, property2 = null }){
    // do stuff
    return something
}
```

From the docs:
[Optional parameters](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#optional-parameters-and-default-values) and [Documenting a destructuring parameter](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#parameters-with-properties)

Answer (score 1):

Optional parameters can be put in `[]` square brackets

```
/**
 * @param {any} param1
 * @param {Object} [param2]
 * 
 * @returns {Object}
 */
function doSomething (param1, { property1 = null, property2 = null }) {}
```

However, I don't think `param2` can be optional AND destructured like that. That won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the official js doc website pertaining to default values, optional parameter etc. Reference: https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#optional-parameters-and-default-values

Look for `Parameters with properties`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing JSDocs for the Closure Compiler you should use `=` to denote optional parameters:

```
* @param {string=} property1
```

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System#optional

But for Object properties, you can use a record type with `|undefined`:

```
/** @param {{required:string, optional:(string|undefined)}} props */
```

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/A-word-about-the-type-Object#records

[Here's a version in the Closure Compiler API thingy](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540formatting%2520print_input_delimiter%252Cpretty_print%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%250A%252F**%2520%2540param%2520%257B%257Brequired%253Astring%252C%2520optional%253A(string%257Cundefined)%257D%257D%2520props%2520*%252F%250Afunction%2520optionalProperties(%257Brequired%252C%2520optional%253Dundefined%257D)%2520%257B%250A%2509return%2520%2560%2524%257Brequired%257D%2520-%253E%2520%2524%257Boptional%2520%253F%2520'provided'%2520%253A%2520'not%2520provided'%257D%2560%253B%250A%257D%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520Warn%2520about%2520missing%2520required%2520parameter.%250Aconsole.log(optionalProperties(%257B%257D))%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520Works%2520fine.%250Aconsole.log(optionalProperties(%257Brequired%253A%2520'given'%257D))%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520Works%2520fine.%250Aconsole.log(optionalProperties(%257Brequired%253A%2520'given'%252C%2520optional%253A%2520'string'%257D))%253B%250A)

Note: I do think this is probably a relatively new feature in the compiler, so your mileage may vary.